# How to guard a mutable object against concurrent read/write access in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, jgrapht

I'm using `jgrapht`, a graph library for java as the backbone of my graph operations. It mutates its state on every change, like adding or removing an edge or a vertex.

I'm accessing this "object" from multiple threads / go-loops.

I've started naively wrapping the graph object with an atom but as far as I understand, it doesn't protect (and can't do) against directly changing the state of its content. Its a safeguard only if you are able to use `reset!` or `swap!` functions.

I've changed to `ref`s and started doing my mutations in `dosync` blocks but I still notice some weird behaviour from time to time. They are hard to pinpoint since they appear on runtime. As you would expect.

I'm not experienced in Clojure ecosystem, so I'd appreciate if you can point me into a couple of alternative strategies for dealing with stateful objects from Java in Clojure.

PS: I'm aware of `loom` and would love to use it, but it lacks for my most important requirement: *finding all simple cycles in a weighted directed graph with negative weights*.

Comment: I wonder if you could store the data in a persistent data structure which goes in the atom.  Then add a watch to the atom that will update the `jgrapht` objects.

Comment: @FrankHenard I think the `locking` approach mentioned in the answers below seems more natural to this use case. I'll look into that first. Thanks for the idea though, It's an interesting one worth exploring if locking doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, that seems like it would be better if it works.  Interested to see how it turns out.

Comment: Well, I think I'm moving away from locking and towards confining all reads/writes to a single thread with the help of two channels (one for read, the other for write) and `alts!`ing them. I'm still experimenting. I'll choose an answer below or post my own when I'm confident of the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note that we recently received a contribution of AsSynchronizedGraph in JGraphT:

https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/concurrent/AsSynchronizedGraph.java

It allows you to protect a graph with a wrapper which uses a ReadWriteLock.  There are a bunch of usage caveats in the Javadoc.

It's not released yet, but it's available in the latest SNAPSHOT build.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure's STM features (eg. dosync, ref) only, as far as I understand them, interact with other features of clojure. They aren't going to interact with mutable Java objects in ways you might hope. The atom type isn't going to help here either unless you felt like copying the entire graph each time you wanted to perform an operation on it. Unfortunately in this case you have a mutable object which has uncertain thread safety characteristics. You're going to have to use some kind of lock. There's a built-in function to acquire the monitor lock: (locking obj body). You could just use the graph itself as the monitor object. Or you can create other kinds of locks like a readwrite like as needed. Each time you access part of the graph or mutate/update it you're going to need to acquire/release the lock.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are talking about a Java class, not a Clojure data structure. If I'm right, there is no sense of wrapping that instance into an atom or any other reference type because the rest of your code will still may modify that instance directly.

Clojure has special `locking` macro that puts a monitor on any Java object while executing a set of actions over it.

Its typical usage might be something like that:

```
(def graph (some.java.Graph. 1 2 3 4))
(locking graph
  (.modify graph)
  (.update graph))
```

See the [documentation page](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/locking) for more info.